# Implementing a custom context in C# for server application

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm implementing a plugin based server architecture, and would like the plugins to be aware of the server state, and to have a common method of reporting status and results back to the server.

My intention is to define a context which is passed to each of the plugins when they are called, and the plugins will report status information back into the context.
The context will then be used to track the status of each task carried out by each plugin.

Is there a standard for creating custom contexts in C#, or is there a generic `Context` object which can be used?

All the context will need to do is store properties, but I'm uncertain which Context class would be the best to extend or use as-is.

In this case, the context will consist of

1) a set of shared properties read by each plugin which will govern their execution (db addresses, folder names for finding items to process etc)

2) A dictionary which will contain results produced by the plugins' `Execute` method

3) Status information as to the success/failure of a process

4) A record of the current state of the process (values from an enum)

I'm intending to use a basic object for this, but as there are a number of `Context` classes in various libraries for C#, I'm debating whether extending an existing `Context` object would be a better choice than just writing one from scratch.

Looking at the literature on MSDN, there doesn't seem to be much precedent for either approach, and I would appreciate any feedback from people who have done this already.

Comment: The term "context" is kind of vague without context. What _exactly_ do you want this "context" to do?

Comment: Agreed, my initial question was too vague. I've elaborated a bit on the intended use - please let me know if you need any more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use global/static contexts. It makes it harder to maintain and test your application.

Instead you can define the context and pass it as an instance to the plugin during plugin initialization. Something like:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    void Init(ApplicationContext context)

    // [.. other methods that plugins must implement ..]
}
```

and just like that you have the same functionality but without having to take `[ThreadStatic]` and async context into account.

> I'm intending to use a basic object for this, but as there are a number of Context classes in various libraries for C#, I'm debating whether extending an existing Context object would be a better choice than just writing one from scratch.

I think it's better to write it from scratch. Do not that context classes tend to grow and move towards GOD objects. By crafting one yourself you can keep it small.

An alternative to context objects is to expose small services to the plugin that they can use instead. A nice way of doing so is to use an inversion of control container to build the classes that implement the `IPlugin` interface.

In that way they can simply use dependency injection to get the application services (their contracts i.e. interfaces) directly.

Something like:

```
//register the plugins in the container
var plugins = Directory.GetFiles(yourAppDirectory, "plugin_*.dll");
foreach (var pluginDll in plugins)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(pluginDll);
    var pluginType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x=> typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(x));
    yourContainer.RegisterType(pluginType, typeof(IPlugin));
}
```

And finally to load them:

```
var plugins = container.ResolveAll<IPlugin>();
foreach(var plugin in plugins)
    plugin.Init();
```

A plugin can then be defined like:

```
public class HelpPlugin : IPlugin, IMenuHandler
{
    public HelpPlugin(IMenuService service)
    {
        service.AddTopMenu("Help", this);
    }

    void IMenuHandler.Handle(MenuClick click)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Menu button was clicked");
    }
}
```

Yay! No need for a context object.

Comment: I'm inclined not to expose services to the plugins to keep things as simple as possible. The majority of the time, the plugins will be for maintenance tasks, and database monitoring. Once they have executed, they need to report their final state, but there will only be a handful of cases where anything else needs to be returned to the management class.

Comment: Then just do as the first paragraphs of the answer ;)

Comment: It's a good point on the static contexts, and on not extending existing context objects. I'll write one from scratch, and keep the interface simple (it only exposes Execute currently), but we do have a second plugin architecture which uses inverted control templates currently that will benefit from this. It uses a file to list available types in the plugin, rather than checking `IsAssignableFrom` when loading plugins. I will look at changing it as per your answer¬ Thank you, that's a huge help!